# Typescript, calling function which is not known to TS leads to red underlining

Tags: c#, function, typescript

I am using typescript in Chromium Embedit framework (CEF).

Now what I am doing is that I am registering C# object and calling it from Javascript, in my solution from typescript.

The issue what I am facing is that since function and this object do not exist in TypeScript calling this function is red underlined.

Can I get somehow rid of this underline for this calling ? This underlining leads to ignoring errors, which is not something what we want.

Comment: You can either create your own Definitely Typed (.d.ts) file that will contain an interface of your class or just cast your object to any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now the issue what I am facing is that since function and this object do not exist in TypeScript calling this function is red underlined

You can declare any global/external variables in a declaration file (`.d.ts` file).

E.g  `mylib.d.ts`

```
declare var awesome:any;
```

Usage `theapp.ts`:

```
awesome(); // No error!
```

PS: You can read more about ambients in TypeScript here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html

Comment: TY, this works ! I am facing one more issue. I am checking for input type of some element, fe checkbox. Now I am sure that I have element that is checkbox, so this element should have property checked. But if I simply do `element.checked` than it is working, but checked is red underlined. I think that i simply have to retype from `HTMLElement` to something like CheckboxElement, but did not find anything suitable for this conversion. How to get rid of this ? I have facing this also in case of `element.value`

Comment: any idea how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put it this way - there is [an example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0A%2F%2F%20plain%20object%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20TS%20is%20doing%20the%20best%20for%20us.%20%0A%2F%2F%20%20it%20informs%20about%20the%20issues%20related%20to%0A%2F%2F%20%20unknown%20properties%20and%20methods%20on%20a%20type%20%3Cany%3E%0Aobj.Result%20%3D%20obj.ReLoad(obj.IdProperty)%3B%0A%0Amodule%20MyNamespace%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09export%20interface%20IObject%20%7B%0A%09%09IdProperty%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%09Result%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09ReLoad%3A%20(id%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20SOLUTION%0A%0A%2F%2F%20I.%20Declare%20type%2C%20and%20implement%20interface%0A%0A%2F%2F%20if%20we%20can%20declare%20a%20type%0Avar%20obj1%3A%20MyNamespace.IObject%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20and%20later%20create%20or%20get%20that%20object%0Aexport%20class%20MyObj%20implements%20MyNamespace.IObject%7B%0A%09IdProperty%3A%20number%3B%0A%09Result%3A%20string%3B%0A%09ReLoad%20%3D%20(id%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7Breturn%20id.toString()%7D%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20now%20we%20get%20the%20implementation%0Aobj1%20%3D%20new%20MyObj()%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20TS%20knows%20what%20could%20do%20with%20the%20obj2%0A%2F%2F%20of%20type%0Aobj1.Result%20%3D%20obj1.ReLoad(obj1.IdProperty)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20II.%20ASSERT%20-%20let%20TS%20know%20what%20is%20the%20type%20behind%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Assert%20-%20say%20to%20TS%3A%0A%2F%2F%20I%20know%20that%20this%20object%20is%20of%20the%20expected%20type%0Avar%20obj2%20%3D%20%3CMyNamespace.IObject%3Eobj%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20now%20TS%20is%20happy%20to%20trust%20that%20tese%20properties%20exist%0Aobj2.Result%20%3D%20obj2.ReLoad(obj2.IdProperty)%3B)

Firstly the issue

```
// plain object
var obj = {};
// TS is doing the best for us. 
//  it informs about the issues related to
//  unknown properties and methods on a type <any>
obj.Result = obj.ReLoad(obj.IdProperty);
```

Introduce interface

```
module MyNamespace {

    export interface IObject {
        IdProperty: number;
        Result: string;
        ReLoad: (id: number) => string;     
    }
}
```

And solution:

```
// I. Declare type, and implement interface

// if we can declare a type
var obj1: MyNamespace.IObject;

// and later create or get that object
export class MyObj implements MyNamespace.IObject{
    IdProperty: number;
    Result: string;
    ReLoad = (id: number) => {return id.toString()};    
}

// now we get the implementation
obj1 = new MyObj();

// TS knows what could do with the obj2
// of type
obj1.Result = obj1.ReLoad(obj1.IdProperty);

// II. ASSERT - let TS know what is the type behind

// Assert - say to TS:
// I know that this object is of the expected type
var obj2 = <MyNamespace.IObject>obj;

// now TS is happy to trust that tese properties exist
obj2.Result = obj2.ReLoad(obj2.IdProperty);
```

Check it [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0A%2F%2F%20plain%20object%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20TS%20is%20doing%20the%20best%20for%20us.%20%0A%2F%2F%20%20it%20informs%20about%20the%20issues%20related%20to%0A%2F%2F%20%20unknown%20properties%20and%20methods%20on%20a%20type%20%3Cany%3E%0Aobj.Result%20%3D%20obj.ReLoad(obj.IdProperty)%3B%0A%0Amodule%20MyNamespace%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09export%20interface%20IObject%20%7B%0A%09%09IdProperty%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%09Result%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09ReLoad%3A%20(id%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20SOLUTION%0A%0A%2F%2F%20I.%20Declare%20type%2C%20and%20implement%20interface%0A%0A%2F%2F%20if%20we%20can%20declare%20a%20type%0Avar%20obj1%3A%20MyNamespace.IObject%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20and%20later%20create%20or%20get%20that%20object%0Aexport%20class%20MyObj%20implements%20MyNamespace.IObject%7B%0A%09IdProperty%3A%20number%3B%0A%09Result%3A%20string%3B%0A%09ReLoad%20%3D%20(id%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7Breturn%20id.toString()%7D%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20now%20we%20get%20the%20implementation%0Aobj1%20%3D%20new%20MyObj()%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20TS%20knows%20what%20could%20do%20with%20the%20obj2%0A%2F%2F%20of%20type%0Aobj1.Result%20%3D%20obj1.ReLoad(obj1.IdProperty)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20II.%20ASSERT%20-%20let%20TS%20know%20what%20is%20the%20type%20behind%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Assert%20-%20say%20to%20TS%3A%0A%2F%2F%20I%20know%20that%20this%20object%20is%20of%20the%20expected%20type%0Avar%20obj2%20%3D%20%3CMyNamespace.IObject%3Eobj%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20now%20TS%20is%20happy%20to%20trust%20that%20tese%20properties%20exist%0Aobj2.Result%20%3D%20obj2.ReLoad(obj2.IdProperty)%3B)